# max_input_vars .htaccess causing 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a large form that is being updated in Wordpress with the plugin spitting out an error saying the max_input_vars is set to 1000. The site is on a shared host and tech support have updated the max_input_vars to 2000 in the php.ini, I have verified this.

I'm trying to add the following to the .htaccess to see if that helps the issue but receive a 500 error, probably bad syntax.

```
php_value max_input_vars 2000
```

Would I need to include this line of code in any particular format, am I missing something? Full .htaccess example below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#php_value max_input_vars 2000
```

Currently the max_input_vars is commented out so it doesn't cause the 500 error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

This one is working for me. Add this section to your .htaccess file in wordpress folder. That's all.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>

 php_value max_input_vars 5000

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You'll need to do this to have it working on 1&1 shared hosting ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a php.ini file in your root wordpress instalation directory. I.E. the same place the htaccess file is.

I personally added all these 3 lines but in most case just the first one will be enpugh:

```
max_input_vars = 3000;
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000;
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000;
```

Comment: The forum plugin still spits out an error saying the max_input_vars limit is 1000. This has been changed on the server php.ini and wordpress dir php.ini